# Getting hardware sensor data from the apk of an android app

Tags: java, android

I am new to Java and android. I am doing a study project on android apps, where in I have to know how these apps are using the motion sensor data. For that I need to decompile and get the source code. I decompiled using two or three of the tools available. But in every app I decompiled, the hardware sensor data is obfuscated. I tried using deobfuscating option in jadx decompiling tool and it did'nt work. The sensor data is still obfuscated. I need to get that code to know how many event listeners the app is registered to and the sampling frequency that is set for that app. Please suggest me on what to do.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the kind of Sensor Data that is required,

- The gravity, linear acceleration, rotation vector, significant motion, step counter, and step detector sensors are either hardware-based or software-based.
- The accelerometer and gyroscope sensors are always hardware-based.

Refer the Official Documentation [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/sensors/sensors_motion.html)

Use

```
public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event){}
```

to get the kind of data that you want.

Comment: yeah, I referred to that. my problem is that I am not getting that sensor related code when I decompiled. When I used apkanalyser in android studio, I can see the methods that are used in classes.dex --> android --> hardware. 
But when I decompile the whole apk for source code, I can't find the code related to that sensor data (guess its obfuscated). I actually want that code that is written for that specific application.

Comment: Can I ask what do want to achieve?

Comment: I need to know if these applications are using the sensor data in some malicious way, like if they are using the data from the sensor to track the location of the user for instance. but its not through the GPS sensor. its through the Zero permission sensors.

Comment: I need one more clarification. What do we actually do when we say we are statically or dynamically analyzing an application?